# Cannot run the batch script successfully when in for-loop

Tags: batch-file

I am facing some difficulties in using batch. My purpose is to use a for-loop to loop all the document in a directory and loop all the line inside each document and replace the string in it..

When I try to do the test:
I test the code with one document only, the code:

```
echo off
set "search=B"
set "replace=A"
set "textfile=Testing.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"

cd/d D:\user\testing

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do(
set "line=%%i"
set local enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
echo(!line!
endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile% %textfile%
```

The input is as follow:
BC
BCB
BCBC

The outcome:
AC
ACA
ACAC

However, things go wrong when I set another for-loop
Code:

```
set "rootDir=D:\user\testing"

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\*") do call :Replace "%rootDir%" "%%~nj" 
goto :eof

:Replace
set "search=B"
set "replace=A"
set "newfile=Output.txt" 

cd /d %1
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%2) do(
set "line=%%i"
set local enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
echo(!line!
endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile% %textfile%
goto :eof
```

In this time all the content in the documents are remove and their document name is showed .

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Is there anythings wrong in the logic?
Please help

Comment: There must be a _space_ between `do` and `(`...

Comment: And no space between `set` and `local` it's `setlocal`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Actually, there are space between do and (. setlocal is also one word. this is the first time I use this forum and I make some typo mistake. Actually, the typo is not existed in the script.

Comment: Please edit your question to correct the code and run it to verify it works exactly as you described it does. Please place `echo on` in the beginning of the script and check what it is doing. Please try to explain what ` the documents are remove and their document name is showed` means exactly. Which documents? Where is it shown - in the file or onscreen? Try replacing brackets and delayed expansion with another `call :Label` - this may make it easier to debug since you will see what exactly is executing after `echo on`. I also suggest wrapping all filenames in double quotes, including %2.